# How to show multiple location points on mkmapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

How to get multiple location pin points on mkmapview.

on my current location I view my friends register with me.

i have got there location latitude and longitude values.

*Below are dummy values for understanding.*

```
{
friendA:
{
latitude: "12.1234";
longtitude: "12.1234";
},

friendB:
{
latitude: "12.1234";
longtitude: "12.1234";
},

friendD:
{
latitude: "12.1234";
longtitude: "12.1234";
}

}
```

Want to show all my friends on mapView with there location 
Placing with PinPointer **Marker.png**

//Created the mapview.

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-60);
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

**MKAnnotation MarkerPin Pointer**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationView";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil){
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Marker.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your friends (do you have them stored in an array or something??) and then call `addAnnotation` for each item.

Something like:

```
for (Friend *friend in friends){
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
   coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
   MKPointAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
   myAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate;
   [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Then, the method that you already implemented, `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` gets called automatically and the annotation is added. Check out this tutorial for more info:http://www.devfright.com/mkpointannotation-tutorial/